# Wpf - Resizing icon, blurry image quantity

Tags: wpf, icons, resize, blurry

I'm attempting to first pull a icon from an executable file, save it to a particular file and display that in a WPF window.

The quality is perfectly fine at 32x32 but when I try to resize it to being larger, it starts to get blurry.

Image from my application, 32x32 image beside 100x100 image:
[Image http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/8967/imageresizemine.jpg](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/8967/imageresizemine.jpg)

As you can see, it's quite blurry, by comparison here's an image from a different application which is getting the icon from executable also (and even larger) so it's obviously possible.
[Image http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1842/imageresizeother.jpg](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1842/imageresizeother.jpg)

There are several topics on this (or at least related) but I'm not managed to figure out what exactly the problem is.

I'm displaying the image using this code.

```
<Image Height="100" 
       Width="100" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Source="{Binding ImagePath}" 
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
```

I assume the issue is with the displaying of the image rather then how it's saved initially but just in case...I'm saving the image using this code.

```
Bitmap image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(FilePath).ToBitmap();   
image.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExtractAssociatedIcon only gets the 32x32 icon, even if the app's resources have others.  You'll probably have to go all the way to p/invoke something to get any of the other icons in an exe.

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ExtractAssociatedIcon.html has some more info

Comment: Oh, that's correct. I looked around originally I all the stuff I saw about icons was 16x16/32x32 so I thought that was all you could get. Looked around again and found this library would takes correctly pulls all the different icon sizes from the exe file. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconLib.aspx